# Solenoid Valve will not open

Tags: diodes, esp8266, solenoid-valve

I've been working on a Wifi gardening project that allows me to water plants from anywhere I want. Of course, this means I need to use a water valve and a MOSFET to control it. The MOSFET feeds power from a 9V battery to the solenoid, and a Huzzah ESP8266 (on a separate 9V battery) controls the MOSFET gate.

I found that the ESP8266 would not open or close the valve, so I started testing the valve and I realized that I could not open the valve at all. The valve is a plastic 12V solenoid valve (https://www.adafruit.com/product/997), but the information on that page indicates that it can be run using 9V. As far as the 3 PSI minimum pressure requirement goes, the valve is connected to a resevoir that is 3-4 feet above the valve, so I figure that I have a decent amount of pressure from gravity.

I have almost no idea what could be going wrong - I connected the 9V battery directly to the solenoid through a breadboard and nothing happened. The only thing that seems off to me is the diode I use for reverse current protection - see the picture below. Is that diode set up correctly?

Thank you very much for your help.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwEoZ1ajLf1uWUhrS2JIU2NnZDQ/view?usp=sharing
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwEoZ1ajLf1uVlJHUm5YS0VVNlE/view?usp=sharing

Comment: A schematic of your circuit is needed. Have you simply tried to turn the valve on and off directly from your 9 volt battery? A typical 9 volt battery will not be able to supply enough current to operate the solenoid.

Comment: 3 psi = 0.2 bar. At 10 m water per bar you need >= 2 m head.

Comment: THe cost of water to fill a rain barrel is cheaper than the battery that might take a couple hours to empty even if it were 2 m above the valve.

Comment: @Transistor I don't quite understand what you mean - do you mean I need 2 m between the resevoir and the valve?

Comment: @GlennW9IQ I have tried to turn the valve on and off by connecting it directly to the 9V.

Comment: Pressure due to gravity is ~ 0.5 psi per vertical foot.  For 3 psi of static pressure, you need 6 feet of water above your valve.

Comment: Yes. In quaint measurements, 3 psi = 6.92 feet water.

Comment: Measure the coil resistance.  Confirm that the coil hasn't been shorted (melted) from soldering the lead wires (and diode) onto the tabs.

Comment: if the diode doesn't get hot, you probably have the correct polarity with red being the switched +9V

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 So the diode looks to be in the right position?

Comment: diode is fine if the red wire is +9V

Comment: @ChrisKnudsen On a multimeter, the solenoid measures 25 ohms when no voltage is applied. When voltage is applied, the multimeter does not display a value, which would indicate to me that the resistance is very large.

Comment: At this current and voltage, this is a probably a pilot driven valve, meaning that you need some pressure to actuate, and the valve will only open with the high pressure side plumbed to the right end.  Try a little more pressure and then switch ends of it doesn't work.

Comment: @AnthonyC Never try to measure resistance with power applied. An ohmmeter works by applying a voltage to the resistor under test and measuring the current flow. Adding an external voltage will, at best, give you a bogus reading or, at worst, destroy your meter!

Comment: @DoxyLover Thanks... can't believe I forgot about that...

Comment: also remember that batteries have internal resistance and ought to be <1% of the load resistance for good voltage regulation. If the 9V battery is say discharged 50% the alkaline batteries can generate about 1 A momentarily with a short circuit implying its internal resistance, ESR has risen to 9 Ohms= 9V/1A thus with a 25 Ohm load the 9V will internally drop 9Ω/(9Ω+25Ω)*100%= 2.65V or 9-2.65=6.35V  . A fresh battery may have lower ESR and a weak battery much higher ESR. So you can see this battery is a poor choice just from voltage regulation alone. also 9V Alk. is only 4.5Wh

Answer (score 2):

Unless the 9V battery is a Lithium cell, Alkaline will not last very long driving a load of 9V  @ 240 mA (from datasheet) or about 37.5 Ohms.

The 9V battery internal resistance with 6 tiny 1.5V cells in series is in the 5 to 20 Ohm range which makes a 9V Alkaline a poor choice for this application with only ~500mAh capacity or 0.5Ah= 0.5A*9V = 4.5Wh.

From the solenoid specs of 4.8W at 12V that  with each application of about 4 watts for 10 seconds resulting in 40 watt-seconds giving you maybe 400 pulses of life.  But battery capacity decreases with rising current due to losses.

If the solenoid was on all the time, it might yield 1 if it is a good industrial Panasonic Alkaline fresh battery and **you had sufficient water pressure for flow.**

- **If not then it wont work at all.**

**It is best to use a small DC water pump than a solenoid.** given you don't have enough pressure nor enough voltage or current with a suitable sized or use a proper DC supply with suitable waterproof and rodent proof cable insulation.

Comment: So, a 9V wouldn't cause any results at all? I'm not particularly concerned about getting long life out of the battery, and the valve will only ever be open for 10 seconds at a time, at most.

Comment: The best practice is to design the system properly based on energy stored in cell and load demand rather than willy nilly guesswork.  So far we dont have enuf data to do this.  A voltmeter will confirm the voltage when energized and 3psi seems to imply you also dont have enough pressure to guarantee flow.

Answer (score 0):

The valve requires a certain amount of pressure to overcome the stiction of the gasket. The spec calls for 3 PSI which means your gravity feed water supply must be at least 7 feet above the valve. Anything less than this means the valve will probably not open - especially when powered by a 9 volt battery.

The solenoid has a diode across it. This is to protect any attached circuits from the reverse voltage that occurs when the solenoid is turned off. If you have ever accidently connected the valve power backwards, there is a good possibility that the diode is now shorted. As a result, the solenoid will not work. You can test this by temporarily removing the diode and powering the solenoid directly with a suitable battery.

The 9 volt battery is probably marginal for this type of application. You could test your solenoid with a 12 volt car battery for comparison. Remember, however, to have the proper water pressure first.

To test the efficacy of your 9 volt battery, measure the voltage across the terminals of the solenoid when the battery is connected. If it drops much below 8.5 volts, it probably will not work.